# Read text file via UDF in pyspark returns unexpected output

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have pyspark dataframe `df` containing paths to text files. I want to create a new column with the content of the text files.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def read_file(filepath): 
    import s3fs
    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
    with s3.open(filepath) as f:
        return f.read()

read_file_udf = F.udf(read_file, StringType())

df.withColumn('raw_text', read_file_udf('filepath')).show()

+---------------------+-----------+
|  file               |   raw_text|
+---------------------+-----------+
|s3://bucket/file1.txt| [B@aa2a4f3|
|s3://bucket/file2.txt|[B@138664c5|
|s3://bucket/file3.txt| [B@3bcc67e|
|s3://bucket/file4.txt|[B@70b735c4|
|s3://bucket/file5.txt|[B@6fad821d|
+---------------------+-----------+
```

Instead of getting the actual file content, I am getting these strange `[B@` codes. What are they, why am I getting them and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question... I was getting `[B@` because the `read_file()` function was returning the byte representation of a string. Defining:

```
def read_file(filepath): 
    import s3fs
    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
    with s3.open(filepath) as f:
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
```

will fix the issue.